# Replicating rows on Pandas Dataframe based on a value column and then affixing a counter column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Suppose I have this dataframe `df`:

```
    A   B   count
0   1   2   3
1   3   4   2
2   5   6   1
3   7   8   2
```

Then I want to do row-replication operation depending on the `count` column, and then add a new column that does the counter. So the resulting outcome is:

```
    counter   A   B   count
0   0         1   2   3
1   1         1   2   3
2   2         1   2   3
3   0         3   4   2
4   1         3   4   2
5   0         5   6   1
6   0         7   8   2
7   1         7   8   2
```

My idea was to duplicate the rows accordingly (using numpy and pandas df). Then add a `counter` column that increments for every row found the same and then reset to 0 once found a new row. But I was thinking this may be slow. Is there any way to do it much easily and not that slow?

Comment: Looking at your profile I notice you've _never_ [accepted an answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer to your question lets others know the question has been solved. There are several really great answers to choose from, please go back through your questions and click the checkmark to the left of whichever answer you feel best solved your problem. (See [What does it mean to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for information)

Comment: Please note I'm not asking you to necessarily accept my answer  as this is a fresh question (although you may if it does indeed solve the problem), but you have questions from years ago that have wonderful answers that have never been marked as solved.

Answer (score 5):

Let's try [`index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) to scale up the DataFrame, then [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to create the groups and [`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) it into the DataFrame at the front:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['count'])]
df.insert(0, 'counter', df.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

`df`:

```
   counter  A  B  count
0        0  1  2      3
1        1  1  2      3
2        2  1  2      3
3        0  3  4      2
4        1  3  4      2
5        0  5  6      1
6        0  7  8      2
7        1  7  8      2
```

---

DataFrame constructor:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 3, 5, 7], 'B': [2, 4, 6, 8], 'count': [3, 2, 1, 2]
})
```